# print out a randint and append it to a list, then loop over and print a totaly different list

Tags: python

Can someone please explain to me why i keep getting the same list but longer instead of a new one?

`[20]`, `[20, 14]`, `[20, 14, 16]`, [`20, 14, 16, 18]`

But i'm trying to get:

`[20]`, `[15, 18]`, `[13, 19, 20]`, `[17, 14, 17, 20]`

```
 import random
 x=[]
 a=0
 while a < 5:
     i=0
     q = 1
     while i < q:
         s=random.randint(10, 20)
         i+=1
         x.append(s)
     print(x)
     q+=1
     a+=1
```

I'm trying to learn python by making small scripts but this on got me stuck.
Please help

Comment: Your indentation is all messed up, which is kind of bad for Python. This will never run. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  I re-arranged a few things like moving your list creation `x=[]` into your outer while loop and moving your `q=1` outside of your outer while loop.

```
import random
a=0
q = 1
while a < 5:
    i=0
    x=[]
    while i < q:
        s=random.randint(10, 20)
        i+=1
        x.append(s)
    print(x)
    q+=1
    a+=1
```

Output:

```
[18]
[15, 17]
[13, 13, 15]
[10, 12, 10, 11]
[20, 12, 20, 11, 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `x` at the beginning of your program, but it sounds like you want to reset it after every print; move your `x = []` line inside your `while` loop, so that each time you enter it, `x` starts off empty.

Also, like @IlmariKaronen said, your code sample cannot run because it is miss-indented.  Presumably it works on your end, so it's not pasted-in correctly.  Do make sure your code samples are runnable when you post a question.